# Asymptotic expansion of ratio function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

I want to expand the following function:

$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{(1-e^{-x})}
$$

$f(x)$ can be rewritten as 
$$
f(x) \sim \frac{1}{x-x^2/2 + x^3/2/3}
$$
But  I want to express big-oh notation such that
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{x} + .... +O(x^2)
$$
up to $x^2$ order.

How to do it?

Comment: Where do you do your expansion? $0$, $\infty$, other? (I reckon the former... but you **should** specify it.)

Comment: And also, if you're expressing this asymptotically in big-O, I believe it would be O(1). But I very well could be wrong.

Comment: Try rewriting  $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x-x^2/2! + x^3/3! +O(x^4)}$ as $f(x) = \dfrac1x\left(\dfrac{1}{1-x/2! + x^2/3! +O(x^3)}\right)$ and then do a series expansion of the contents of the bracket

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}=\frac{1}{x-x^2/2+x^3/6+O(x^4)} \\
=\frac{1}{x} \frac{1}{1-x/2+x^2/6+O(x^3)} \\
=\frac{1}{x} (1+x/2-x^2/6+x^2/4+O(x^3))$$

where in the last step we used the identity $\frac{1}{1-y}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty y^m$ whenever $|y|<1$. Note that in this case $y=(-x/2+x^2/6+O(x^3))$ and so the $x^2$ term has a contribution from two factors of $x/2$ as well as a contribution from one factor of $x^2/6$.

Answer (score 1):

Around $0$:
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)}
= \frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{6}+o(x^2)}
$$
*(Advice: when doing Taylor expansions, avoid the equivalents $\sim$, which are made to capture the first term only. Confusions and mistake may arise very quickly otherwise.)*

Now, use the fact that $\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{6}+o(x^2) \xrightarrow[x\to0]{}0$, and that $$\frac{1}{1+u} = 1-u+u^2 + o(u^2)$$ when $u\to 0$ (your $u$ will be $-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{6}+o(x^2)$):
$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= \frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{6}+o(x^2)}
= \frac{1}{x} \left(1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{6}+o(x^2)+\left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{6}+o(x^2)\right)^2\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{x} \left(1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{6}+o(x^2)+\left(\frac{x^2}{4}+o(x^2)\right)\right)
= \frac{1}{x} \left(1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{6}+o(x^2)+\frac{x^2}{4}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{x} \left(1+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{12}+o(x^2)\right)
= \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x}{12}+o(x)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Your formula for $\frac{1}{1+u}$ is wrong.

Comment: Yes, correcting it... my apologies.

Comment: Corrected. (Also, note that whenever I wrote $o(x^c)$ above, the statement $O(x^{c+1})$ actually also holds, so the result can be easily shown to $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2} + \frac{x}{12} + O(x^2)$ as well.)

Answer (score 1):

We can consider the complex function $f(z):=\frac{1}{1-e^{-z}}$, it is easy to see that $f$ has a simple pole with residue $1$ at $z=0$, thus $\frac{1}{1-e^{-z}}  -\frac{1}{z}$ is holomorphic on a neighborhood of the origin, then we can expand it as Taylor series:
$$\frac{1}{1-e^{-z}}-\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{12}z+O(z^2).$$
It follows that 
$$\frac{1}{1-e^{-z}}=\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{12}z+O(z^2).$$

Comment: I think the main point of the question is *how* to perform the step where "we can expand it as Taylor series."

Comment: It is just the usual taylor expansion $f(z)=f(0)+f'(0)z+O(z^2)$.